Does anyone recognize this front door?
I hired a window company to replace all the windows in my vacation house. We double checked everything before placing the order, everything was correct on the order form as to which windows and doors were being replaced. However somehow there was a mixup on the company’s end, and they ordered a random front door. It was installed and the old door disposed of before we realized the error.
I am trying to find the original door, as it was only a couple years old and I like the original door much more than the new one.
Does anyone recognize this door? It’s an impact door that meets Miami Dade requirements.
(And yes I’ve reached out to the previous owner who replaced the door, I’ve tried to hunt down the contractor who replaced the door, I’ve checked the permits at town hall, I’ve image google searched - so far, no luck).
The only info from the glass on the doors that I have:


Update
Yes, one way or another I am having the contractor install a new door that I like, at their cost. I liked the original door and the color, so the easiest option is to just replace it exactly. But so far I’m unable to even figure out the brand of the original door.

If the window contractor replaced the wrong door, it's their responsibility to make things right.   Make the contractor install a door to your liking, or don't pay them.
